# Why double quotes added to a javascript object property?

Tags: javascript

I am iterating over a list of bills to check how much income there is each month.

```
let total = 0
for (const singleBill of bills) {
    const date = new Date(singleBill.appointment.date);
    const month = date.toLocaleString("fr-FR", {month: "long"});
    if (periodAmounts[month]) periodAmounts[month] += singleBill.amount;
    else periodAmounts[month] = singleBill.amount;
    total += singleBill.amount;
}
console.log(periodAmounts);
```

I don't understand the quotes that appears around month name `"février"` and not `janvier`. What could explain it ?

```
// output of console log : Object { "février": 0, janvier: 50 }
```

**Update**

Turns out the browser I was using (firefox ubuntu) automatically adds quotes to the property if there are special characters. Here `février` is changed to `"février"`

Could not provide valid snippet / codepen since its browser related.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] in a live snippet (and mention which browser)? Looks interesting, I'd suspect it has something to do with the `é`, but I can't reproduce it ATM on Chrome 71

Comment: Which JavaScript environment are you running this code on? I am not getting the quotes in console.log output in chrome if I test an object with those properties.

Comment: Firefox. In chrome indeed there is no quotes issue. Not an issue but it was bugging me. Is there something I should change to my code tho ? Or add quote somewhere ?

Comment: I see the quotes in Firefox as well. This is strange.

Comment: Firefox ubuntu quantum 1.0

Comment: It looks like the é character causes this in Firefox. Perhaps it's all unicode characters. It doesn't seem like a problem, just a Firefox quirk.

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Comment: There's a couple of nice articles, [Valid JavaScript variable names in ES5](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers), [Valid JavaScript variable names in ES2015](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers-es6) and [Unquoted property names / object keys in JavaScript](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties) by Mathias Bynens that may be helpful. Especially, there are listed some bugs that affect browsers' behaviour.